# TypeError: this.abc is not a function | javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Not a fronted or JavaScript so not able to understand why it's not able to find the defined function in the file. I am integrating Apple Pay and I am trying to call the back-end API based on certain event. Here is my code.

```
ACC.payDirect = {
_autoload: ['payDirect'],

session: null,
payDirect: function () {
    let button = $('#mbutton');
    if (button.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $('#mbutton').on('click', this.onButtonClicked.bind());

},

onButtonClicked: function () {
    if (!Session) {
        return;
    }

    var request =  getCartPaymentRequest();
    this.requestSession("1234"); //getting error while calling this function
    session.begin();
},


requestSession: function (validationURL) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ACC.config.encodedContextPath + '/checkout/request_session',
            data: JSON.stringify({ validationURL: validationURL }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: resolve,
            error: reject
        });
    });
},
```

},

```
function getCartPaymentRequest() {
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ACC.config.encodedContextPath + '/checkout/payment-request',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {

            result = response;
        },

    });
    return result;
}
```

While calling the `requestSession` I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: this.requestSession is not a function. (In 'this.requestSession("1234")', 'this.abc' is undefined)
```

I am sure doing some basic mistake but not able to find out the root cause as why it's not able to find the second function while the first one seems to be working without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the .bind method you called without any parameters.

Take the following example:

```js
const obj2 = {
  b: function (callback) {
    callback()
  }
};

const obj = {
  a: function () {
    obj2.b(this.c.bind())
  },
  c: function () {
    console.log(this)
  }
};

obj.a()
```

What will happen here is that the Window object will appear in the console.

This happens because the window is somewhat of the global context, and when running in the browser JavaScript's bind's parameter will default to the only context it can: the window.

What you need to do is call the .bind method using the `ACC.payDirect` as parameter as it will then bind it to the object and use the proper context, you could use a `this` but if the methodm was called with a different context would cause problems. An even better solution (provided you can use new ES features) is using arrow functions. They are much, much better to work with and won't give you headaches such as this.